# Trouble installing Android 4.2 APIs

Tags: android

I updated ADT through Eclipse today to version 21. Now when I open the SDK Manager I would expect there to be a folder like "Android 4.2 (API 17)", which would contain the SDK Platform and APIs, documentation, etc. However, instead I just get a folder called "API 17", and the only thing in it is "Google APIs", which I can't even install because

> Installing this package also requires installing:
>   - Missing SDK Platform Android, API 17

What do I do here? Thanks

Answer (score 225, accepted):

I figured this out myself after some poking around. I went into the settings for the SDK Manager, cleared the cache, and told it to use HTTPS, then refreshed the listing and it all appeared normally.

Comment: Don't think you need to use https, it seems to work fine after clearing the cache and refreshing.

Comment: That's odd, in my installation the clear cache option was in the AVD Manager, under tools - options.

Comment: Works fine after clearing the cache and refreshing. Thanks for all your research

Comment: All I had to do is click "Reload" from the menubar.

Comment: Thanks.  This was another obtuse Eclipse/Android situation - sometimes dealing with Android drives me nuts.  This solution definitely fixes it.

Answer (score 54):

Eclipse > Window > **Android SDK Manager** > **Packages** > **Reload**

It then properly updated the UI to let me choose updated software.

Why do I need to click "Reload" manually ?!
I expect that to happen automatically when I open the SDK Manager.

Comment: +1 - It worked for me. The manual "Reload" option is kind of hidden... it's in the menus (I didn't even notice the window had a menu until I read this answer.)

Comment: Damn, there is a menu in this window!

Answer (score 16):

By this step~

1)
Eclipse > Window > Android SDK Manager > Packages > Reload

2)
then install the sdk

ref: http://my.eoe.cn/iceskysl/archive/1027.html

Answer (score 11):

Eclipse > Window > Android SDK Manager > Preferences > Clear Cache Button click> Done.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem in ubuntu.

- Open a terminal and navigate to the android-sdk-linux folder: 
  `cd android-sdk-linux`
- Then manually update the sdk:
  `tools/android update sdk -u`

After it is done, restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

As error suggest : API 18 depends on SDK version n etc etc. 
So first update SDK tool to latest version (deselect API 18) then try to install API 18.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me..
Before trying this i tried:
-updating Eclipse
-Refresh the Android SDK Manager
-Clear the cache of the Android SDK Manager
-Set to only fetch from https.

Only thing that worked for me was to first only update the SDK Tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try approving each package one by by instead of doing approve all. If any package has an error, you can't download all at the same time.