# Choose package to install - install button greyed out

Tags: eclipse

I'm attempting to install a collection of packages using the sdk manager, but even after selecting "Accept all", the "Install" button remains greyed out.

I can see some text saying "this package depends on 'missing SDK platform Android, API 17', but don't know what I need to do to install the 'missing SDK platform Android, API 17'... should it be in the list of things to install that I'm already seeing in the SDK manager?... is it there under a slightly different name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the officially available packages. To make sure you see them, have a look at these menu items

- Tools -> Manage AVD addon sites. The main sites should all be checked.
- Packages -> Show new/Updated packages. It should be checked.
- Packages -> Reload. That way you can force the SDK manager to re-download all information. It normally caches the information for 24 hours, which can lead to not showing available packages, if the information was corrupted on last download.

Answer (score 16):

You need to update ONLY the SDK tools first--its blocking on that.

This worked for me: Click on "Deselect All" to clear all selections. Then, under Tools, select all the packages (Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools", etc.).

Install these package first. Close down the SDK manager and ADT, and restart it. Then do the same thing for the API (API18 for me) and then rinse and repeat for the other packages.

Comment: Awesome if i select the checkbox before 'tools', the install packages button is greyed out. Interesting user experience you got going here, android!

Answer (score 1):

it seems to work fine after clearing the cache and refreshing.

Look at this link:
[Trouble installing Android 4.2 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372835/trouble-installing-android-4-2-apis)