# Unable to install android sdk packages (in windows 7)

Tags: android, sdk, installation, java

While installing android sdk packages, the install option is not visible even after selecting accept all.
[image: install option unavailable]

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435007/choose-package-to-install-install-button-greyed-out)

Answer (score 0):

Launch SDK Manager as administrator. For older versions you can do it in the Start Menu->Android->SDK Manager->right click and select Run as administrator. Or just search the file in Windows Explorer and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Because some of them already installed .

installing all  one by one

or try in  older versions .